# How do I make use of the remote disc icon in the sidebar of Finder?

Tags: macos, finder

I bought the new Mac Mini, which doesn't have a SuperDrive, and I noticed an icon in the sidebar of the Finder: Remote Disc.

[image: screenshot]

To which device is referring?
When I clicked over the sidebar icon with the right button, to get information about the device, I got just genetic information that didn't help me to understand if it is referring to a specific device, and how I can "connect" such device to the Mac Mini.

[image: screenshot]

Can I associate the "Remote Disc" with a MacBook's SuperDrive?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Remote Disc is a way for Macs without optical drives (Air, mini) to access another computers optical drive over a network. So you can put a disc in another Mac or Windows PC and read it on your mini.

[Full details and instructions are reported here.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1777?viewlocale=en_US)

On the computer with the CD/DVD drive:

- Go to the Preference panel, and click on "Sharing."

  [image: screenshot]
- In Sharing, enable the "CD and DVD Sharing" service.

  [image: screenshot]
- When a CD/DVD is inserted in the computer used to share the CD/DVD, its content will be show under "Remote Disc" on the Mac Mini.

Comment: Documenting at least a few key steps would make this answer a lot higher quality.

Comment: Also, I would add that the steps above are for the machine with the CD/DVD player. On the machine without a drive, you just find the shared CDs/DVDs under that icon.